# Auto-fit and auto-fill in css grid not work when i try do my grid responsive

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Auto-fit and auto-fill in CSS grid not working correctly, grid should generate new rows when screen width gets smaller. instead, the track gets smaller and never generates new rows.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid{
    outline: 3px solid;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 90px auto;
    display: grid;
    align-items: stretch;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(300px,1fr));
    grid-auto-flow: column;   
}

.grid__item {
    /--height: 100px/
    background: dodgerblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
   /*width: 300px;
     height: var(--height);
    line-height: var(--height);*/
}

.grid__item--one{

}

.grid__item--second{
  background: darkorange;
}
.grid__item--third{
  background: slateblue;
}

.grid__item--fourth{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid"> 
    <div class="grid_item grid_item--one">#1</div>
    <div class="grid_item grid_item--second">#2</div>
    <div class="grid_item grid_item--third">#3</div>
    <div class="grid_item grid_item--fourth">#4</div>
</section>
```

Why CSS grid no generate automatically the new rows? I follow YouTube tutorials and documentation on the internet and nothing appears to works.
Why CSS grid no generate automatically the new rows? I'm following  YouTube tutorials. and documentation on the internet. and nothing appears to work. Do I need to update on anything?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the property `grid-auto-flow`. By mentioning this property you are telling CSS to alter the default auto-flow algorithm. This results in giving all the min-width (300px) to at-least one element when screen size gets smaller.

Removing it made it behave as expected, here is the code:

```css
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid{
    outline: 3px solid;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 90px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax(300px,1fr));
}
```

```html
<section class="grid"> 
        <div class="grid_item grid_item--one">#1</div>
        <div class="grid_item grid_item--second">#2</div>
        <div class="grid_item grid_item--third">#3</div>
        <div class="grid_item grid_item--fourth">#4</div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check your HTML code since you are using BEM notation you missed an underscore in your grid items.